# How are old versions of a application handled with the PublishSingleFile option?

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-3.0, .net-core-publishsinglefile

Do aplications build with the PublishSingleFile clean up old versions? If not is there a way to reliably clean them up automatically?

Csproj example for reference:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>ubuntu.16.04-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
```